# Enable Xamarins.Forms App to Trust IIS Express Development Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, iis-express

I'm developing my first Xamarin.Forms App and have a backend API built using ASP.Net Core. I want all calls to the API to be via HTTPS so followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/https#iisxpresshttp://) for setting up HTTPS for development in ASP.NET Core. This, I believe, will let me use the IIS Express Development Certificate from within Visual Studio.

Up to this point I had been making all calls to the API from my Xamarin.Forms Android App via the emulator using `HttpClient` and the following http uri

```
http://10.0.2.2:44321/api/User
```

but now with SSL enabled for my API I need to make the call from the app using the following uri

```
https://10.0.2.2:44321/api/User
```

However, simply changing `http` to `https` gives the following error

```
{Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. ---> Java.Security.Cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I presume this is because the the Xamarin.Forms App does not list the IIS Development Certifcate as being trusted, i.e., with Swagger ([Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)) running from my API I can hit the endpoint with no problems; with postman running with `SSL certificate verification` turned off I can also hit the endpoint.

How can I setup a Xamarin.Forms App (specifically Android) to trust the IIS Development Certificate for development purposes?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with this right now...